# SQL - passing variable from first select to second select

Tags: sql, select

I have one table `things` full of items listed by `ItemID`. Given an ItemID, I need to get the record with the ItemID and all other items with the same `name`.

In the sample data below, given the ItemID of 1, I need to select all records with the same name (in this case, "poptarts") as ItemID 1, including the record with ItemID 1.

```
ItemID = 1 name = poptarts
ItemID = 7 name = poptarts
ItemID = 8 name = cheddar
ItemID = 323 name = poptarts

select a.ItemID, a.name from things where a.ItemID = '1'
UNION
select b.ItemID, b.name from things where b.name = a.name
```

The SQL I've written above however does not pass a.name to the second select. Is there any way to pass the first name value to the second select? I would like for the statement to return itemid = 1 as the first row and 7 and 323 as the other rows.

Comment: where do you have to try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` is only really used to concatenate two distinct sets. Based on your example, you could probably do something like this:

```
SELECT a.ItemID, a.Name
FROM things a
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM things WHERE itemID = 1)
```

There are lots of ways to write this kind of query and will depend on which flavor of SQL you're using but this should be more or less universal.

Comment: This returns every row. ItemID 1, ItemID 2, ItemID 3, all all items have different names.

Comment: so what happens if you take out the subquery and just put in the `name` value i.e. `SELECT a.itemID, A.name FROM Things a WHERE Name = 'poptarts'`

Comment: That returns what I want, just not by item id passed in.

Comment: and if you run just the subquery, you get "poptarts" if so, double check the copy/paste and maybe consider replacing "IN" with "=" if itemID is unique in your table (though that shouldn't make a difference)

Comment: If I run the subquery I just get the row with ItemID = 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21416/discussion-between-m-m-and-douglas-bubbletrousers)

Comment: I made a stupid mistake with my data. Your code was correct all along.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  a.itemID,
  a.name
from
  things a
where a.name in (
  select name
  from things b
  where b.itemID = '1'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT this.name, this.id, that.id
FROM thing this
LEFT JOIN thing that ON that.name=this.name AND that.id <> this.id
WHERE this.id = 1
   ;
```

NOTE: this also selects the this-rows that have no twin records; in that case the that.id will be NULL. If you want to suppress the records without twin-records, remove the `LEFT`.

UPDATE: added the id <> id clause to suppres the obvious match.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only have one table, no need to bring it in twice, `UNION`, or anything fancy like htat.

```sql
SELECT 
    name
FROM
    a --assuming this is your only table
GROUP BY 
    itemID, name
HAVING
    itemID = '1'
```